# String Similarity using elastic search

Tags: string, postgresql, go, elasticsearch, similarity-search

Let me explain the problem:

I have data something like this.

- ward no 02 vlg nadinal teh bhattiyat bharari 273 chambachamba hp chamba 176301
- ward no 02 vlg madinal teh bhattiyat bharari 273 chambachamba hp chamba 176301 (see 1 character difference)
- madinal teh bhattiyat bharari chamba 176307 (pincode can be different)
- bharari chamba hp 176302

What I want to achieve is, if I give some input string say `madinal bhatiyat chamba hp 176302`. I should get all the strings which exceeds a particular threshold. (Considering all semantic and jumbled versions). I am planning to use elastic search but I am new to this. So I need suggestions, what to use and how to use.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html + https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/go-api/current/getting-started-go.html#_searching_documents after 2 min in google